# ScrollToItemAt in UICollectionView does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I create a horizontal menu using the UICollectionView in Storyboard (Swift). There was a problem when scrolling the collection to the active cell - the scrolling works correctly only without updating the collection. And I need to update it in order to display an active cell (text color and line at the bottom, which are hidden in a non-active cell). The essence of the problem is clearly visible in the animations that are attached to the code.

How can I correct the problem and make a truly worker menu?

**CODE 1**
scroll is correct, cells is not reload
[gif-demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb2UB.gif)

```
//1
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  collectionMenu.isPagingEnabled = false
  collectionMenu.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
  collectionMenu.isPagingEnabled = true

}
```

**CODE 2**
cells reloaded, but scroll is broken
[gif-demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pww7F.gif)

```
//2
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  collectionMenu.reloadData() //change design active cell
  collectionMenu.isPagingEnabled = false
    collectionMenu.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    collectionMenu.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
  collectionMenu.isPagingEnabled = true

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reloading the collectionView on `didSelectItem(at:)` you'll want to update the cell styling manually from there. I don't think there's also any need to toggle paging on the collectionView on and off from didSelect either.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionMenu.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)

    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? YourCell else { return }
    cell.titleLabel.text = // Your orange colour
}
```

You may also need to override the `prepareForReuse` method inside your cell like so to prevent dequeuing issues such as the text colour displaying at the wrong time etc.

```
class YourCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
        titleLabel.text = // Your default grey colour
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried this, but I still need to update the collection to get a new cell width (the text inside changes the font instep on fat, and therefore does not fit inside). Updating an isolated cell using reloadItems(at: [indexPath]) does not work correctly and disrupts the scroll. How can I get a new cell width or update the collection?

(isPagingEnabled — this property helped to align the item exactly in the center, since sometimes scrolling worked not as needed (when I tried to use the reloadData() and layoutIfNeeded() )